# int A does not equal int B

Tags: java

I have two integers that I want to compare. The first integer is created from a byte of utf-8 and the second integer is the one I want to check to see if it equals.

```
int a = 106;  
int b = (int)byteArray[0]; //which actually equals 106 when you printstatement it
```

but....

```
(a==b) //always equals false
int i = 0;    While(b != i) { println(i); i++;} //eventually escapes the loop and is true
```

Are primitives also referenced when created? And why does a never equal b unless I count all the way up to 106?

Is there a better way to compare bytes? because I've tried all forms of variables and they do not work either.

Comment: Create an SSCCE that we can compile and run.

Comment: I just created a SSCCE for this and it gave the output as true. `byte b1 = 106;
  int a = 106;  
  int b = (int) b1;
  System.out.println(a==b);`. Can you say how exactly its different from the SSCCE I used?

Comment: That is not a SSCCE. In particular, it is not self-contained.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is somewhere else in your code (in the part that you are not showing). This is why you are being suggested to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

The following works as expected (i.e. prints `true`):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { 106 };
        int a = 106;  
        int b = (int) byteArray[0];
        if (a == b)
            System.out.println("true");
    }
}
```

Most probably, in your code `byteArray[0]` does NOT contain 106. An SSCCE would show this.

Comment: +1 s/most probably/as sure as 2+2 is 4/

Comment: Turns out it was just the logic of my code and that I had accidentally re assigned it later on. I thought I was just going crazy for a second. I would delete this question to spare the embarasment but I do not know how since this was my first question.

Comment: That's why SSCCEs are helpful :)